# "composer network ping" won't show the participant after "composer identity issue"

Tags: hyperledger-composer

I am following steps in https://fabric-composer.github.io/managing/identity-issue.html to check the identity issuing for participants. I get no errors and when executing:

```
composer identity issue -n 'mychain-network' -i WebAppAdmin -s DJY27pEnl16d -u user1 -a "com.example.model.Owner#userid"
```

I get correctly:

```
The participant can now connect to the business network with the following details:
  userID = user1
  userSecret = kJoWHaYCxnes
```

The problem is that later I don't get the participant when pinging:

```
$ composer network ping -n 'mychain-network' -i user1 -s kJoWHaYCxnes
The connection to the network was successfully tested:
  version = 0.5.5
  participant = <no participant found>
Command completed successfully.
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work with fabric v0.6, you need to start up the membership service with the following environment variable
`MEMBERSRVC_CA_ACA_ENABLED=true`
easiest way to do this is to update your docker compose file, for example

  `membersrvc:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-membersrvc
    ports:
      - '7054:7054'
    environment:
      - MEMBERSRVC_CA_ACA_ENABLED=true
    command: membersrvc`

your example should then have the participant field with the correct value.