# Hyperledger composer ACL definition does not work (verified example)

Tags: hyperledger-composer

Ok so here is what I've got:

1. Setup local fabric using docker compose.
2. Deployed business network with basic acl, created and enrolled participants, as well as assets using admin id and secret.
3. composer-rest-server using participants id and secret.
4. Can still see asset (despite DENY acl) in explorer.

I've posted the .bna and verification steps in github.

https://github.com/wajid-poernomo/sample-business-network

Be great to get some input here as there seem to be lot's of contributors who treat acl as a given. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Same problem here - only using composer-client api with node JS. Spent last couple of days already on this problem.

Comment: Can you please try a `composer network ping` using the identity that you have issued? It should echo the associated participant.

Comment: The participant id imply that the Fabric in use here is v0.6.  Is anybody seeing the same issue on a 1.0 Fabric? Looking over the sample provided   (which is very helpful thanks!)

Comment: Thanks for this. Tried the ping and showed did not show participant - after this traced the problem to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894228/composer-network-ping-wont-show-the-participant-after-composer-identity-issu. Working now on v6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In summary, the problem was due to not having an attribute set on membership services as described here.
["composer network ping" won't show the participant after "composer identity issue"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42894228/composer-network-ping-wont-show-the-participant-after-composer-identity-issu)